# How to Fix Virtual Floppy Drive Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, floppy

I am following the OSDev tutorial over at brokenthorn, and a part of it is creating a virtual floppy drive using vfdwin.exe. I downloaded it from the sourceforge page, and while there is another thread on this page about fixing it, but my problem is not that it it doesn't support 64-bit systems(the problem at the thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/183335/how-to-create-a-virtual-floppy-drive#)). When I run it, a dialog box opens saying it does not run on windows 95/96/me. Any reason why? I am running windows 7 not 95. What might be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: DId you complete the instuctions by insuring that the program is run in the compatabilty mode?  "run this program in compatibility mode for XP and also select run this as an administrator"

Comment: Yes, but it still says that it does not run in Windows 95/98/Me