# How to run a CD-ROM application which needs mscdex with the parameter /d:mscd001?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

The application is called Software Toolworks Encyclopedia. It can't find CD-ROM drive when it is run under Windows XP. The same problem occured when it was run under windows 98 unless the bootable diskette was used instead of HD. (The bootable diskette contained MSCDEX. Unfortunately, my diskette drive is out of order.) Thanks in advance!

Comment: What other things have you tried?  Did you copy the whole CD onto the hard drive and run the install from there?  Pretend you copied the CD into d:\cdrom   Then also try (admin command prompt) **subst o: d:\cdrom**  Then run the install from O: can see if it operates.  Did you try a full CD-ROM emulator?

Comment: I suppose that the bootable diskette from my old Win98 computer needs its own CD-ROM drive, but I feel too powerless to try it. Excuse me, please.

Comment: Have you thought about buying a USB floppy disk drive you can just plug in?

Comment: Also have you considered just buying something new as when I search for it, it is from 1992?  Much has changed in the information we have recorded in the world since 1992.

Comment: https://www.bonanza.com/listings/Microsoft-Encyclopedia-Encarta-Reference-Library-2007/254752592?goog_pla=1&gpid=76984043941&keyword=&goog_pla=1&pos=16o17&ad_type=pla&gclid=CjwKEAiA_p_FBRCRi_mW5Myl4S0SJAAkezZrvHngHkiODrMKG_eVfw9bvKGOCYWI6PdYzZAhGRHkvhoC52Pw_wcB

Answer (score 0):

You [can use](https://msfn.org/board/topic/129297-help-me-in-creating-a-pure-dos-boot-cd/#comment-831831) a virtual floppy disk driver (of which there are many examples [here](https://superuser.com/questions/183335/how-to-create-a-virtual-floppy-drive)).

Please take also note that MSCDEX*NT* seems to be [slightly](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=503) [older](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=280) than the original DOS one (and it has been further [gimped](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=6225&start=300#p147504) in Vista).